# Jhipster REST prevent spam while Signing Up

Tags: security, spring-security, jhipster

I am using the JHipster to create a web app and i have written a signUp function that takes in username, password and mobile no;

A public API available here : http://localhost:8080/api/signUp

How do we prevent a robot from calling this sequentially ?

```
curl -X POST\
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json'  \
'http://localhost:8080/api/signUp?username=kaka1&password=kaka&emailId=k1aka%40kka.com&mobile=6777777-&firstName=kaka&dateOfBirth=1988-11-11&sex=1
```

I have allowed the CORS  origin request to be allowed since the call is made from the mobile :

```
cors:
    allowed-origins: "*"
    allowed-methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
    allowed-headers: "*"
    exposed-headers:
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
```

Do we use any filters to check if the request is originating from the same machine ?
Little confused to handle this issue

Other non public API's are secure as we request a TOKEN.

Comment: Have you considered using Google Re-Captcha?